# deltaspike repository entitymanagerresolver error with two produces entityManger

Tags: cdi, deltaspike

Sorry for my english, I've a war project with cdi 1.0, deltaspike 0.5 and primefaces 4.0, when I'm trying to use @Respository with @EntityManagerConfig because I've two produces for entityManager with diferent @Qualifiers, I'm using glassfish 4 for application server this is de code for Repository, Produces and EntityManagerResolver:

Repository:

```
@Repository(forEntity = User.class)
@EntityManagerConfig(entityManagerResolver = HbsWebEntityManagerResolver.class, flushMode = FlushModeType.AUTO)
public abstract class UserRepository extends
    AbstractEntityRepository<User, Integer> {

   @Query(named = User.BY_LOGIN)
   public abstract User findByLoginEqual(@QueryParam("login") String login);

}
```

EntityManagerResolver:

```
public class HbsWebEntityManagerResolver implements EntityManagerResolver{

    @Inject
    @HbsWeb
    private EntityManager hbsWebEntityManager;

    @Override
    public EntityManager resolveEntityManager() {       
        return hbsWebEntityManager;
}

}
```

Produces:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="HBS")
        private EntityManagerFactory hbsEntityManager;

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="HBSWEB")
    private EntityManagerFactory hbsWebEntityManager;

    @Produces
    @Hbs    
    protected EntityManager createHbsEntityManager() {
        return hbsEntityManager.createEntityManager();
    }

    protected void closeHbsEntityManager(
            @Disposes @Hbs EntityManager entityManager) {
        if (entityManager.isOpen()) {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }

    @Produces
    @HbsWeb 
    protected EntityManager createHbsWebEntityManager() {
        return hbsWebEntityManager.createEntityManager();
    }

    protected void closeHbsWebEntityManager(
            @Disposes @HbsWeb EntityManager entityManager) {
        if (entityManager.isOpen()) {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }

}
```

When I try to use the repository with @inject I get the follow error:

```
org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.QueryInvocationException: Exception calling Repository: [Repository=class    co.com.compuhelmac.hbs.repository.UserRepository_$$_javassist_0,method=findByLoginEqual],exception=class org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException,message=WELD-001318 Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between [Producer Method [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@Hbs @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Hbs protected co.com.compuhelmac.hbs.database.EntityManagerProducer.createHbsEntityManager()], Producer Method [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@HbsWeb @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @HbsWeb protected co.com.compuhelmac.hbs.database.EntityManagerProducer.createHbsWebEntityManager()]]
    at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.QueryHandler.invoke(QueryHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.partialbean.impl.PartialBeanAbstractMethodHandler.invoke(PartialBeanAbstractMethodHandler.java:44)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.partialbean.impl.MethodHandlerProxy.invoke(MethodHandlerProxy.java:35)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy549.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at co.com.compuhelmac.hbs.repository.UserRepository_$$_javassist_0.findByLoginEqual(UserRepository_$$_javassist_0.java)
    at co.com.compuhelmac.hbs.security.HbsLoginEJB.login(HbsLoginEJB.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001318 Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between [Producer Method [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@Hbs @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Hbs protected co.com.compuhelmac.hbs.database.EntityManagerProducer.createHbsEntityManager()], Producer Method [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@HbsWeb @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @HbsWeb protected co.com.compuhelmac.hbs.database.EntityManagerProducer.createHbsWebEntityManager()]]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.resolve(BeanManagerImpl.java:1154)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:798)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.EntityManagerLookup.lookupFor(EntityManagerLookup.java:51)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.QueryHandler.createContext(QueryHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.QueryHandler.invoke(QueryHandler.java:74)
```

Does anyone know why this error happens?

Answer (score 0):

Going by your stacktrace

```
org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.EntityManagerLookup.lookupFor(EntityManagerLookup.java:51)
```

and taking a look at the sources of DeltaSpike 0.5, I'd say this is a bug in the 0.5 release, since the `EntityManager` obtained from the `EntityManagerResolver` is never used.

Try again with a DeltaSpike 0.6-SNAPSHOT - there are many improvements in the Data module, and this particular piece of code looks more correct now.

Answer (score 0):

Your EM resolver is getting called, but the problem is when trying to inject to

```
@Inject
@HbsWeb
private EntityManager hbsWebEntityManager;
```

Due to a resolution problem  between : createHbsWebEntityManager() and createHbsEntityManager()

How are the @HbsWeb and  @Hbs  defined?  are they related?